# Is there a way to know when an app uses a permission in real time?

Tags: android, kotlin

For example, Google Maps use the location permission to access the location, so is there a way to detect that in real time programmatically?

I want to know when some API requiring permissions is used and by which app.

Comment: You might want to be more specific in what you're looking for. What does real time mean to you; and what do you mean with detect? Do you want to know what permissions an app requests? Do you want to know when some API requiring permissions is used...

Comment: Yes I want to know when some API requiring permissions is used and by which app.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to detect them when you use a feature and if android studio don't find related permission it will show you a message. You need to use android studio 3.+ version.

Also you can check this link to know which features need which permission.
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/permissions/overview